# IntelliJ IDEA 14 with Scene Builder 2.0

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx-8, scenebuilder

IntelliJ IDEA 14 now has the Interface of Scene Builder inside, but i'm using Scene Builder 2.0-b20 and the IntelliJ version is not working properly; shows all boxes in a "white style".

My question is, it is compatible with Scene Builder 2.0?

Comment: According to this Idea 14 should be compatible with Scene Builder 2.0 https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14+EAP ...

Comment: Well, i´ve been testing it with two different computers, and show the same problem with both..

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by shows all boxes in a white style, but this bug report seems to address that problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-130580.

Comment: Exactly. Thats the problem...

Comment: Then there's probably nothing that can be done at the momemt except voting for that issue on YouTrack so it gets fixed as soon as possible. I just voted for it myself :)